# How to wait for all responses of WCF Method ?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

I have WCF method that take the scores of all players(clients) and add them to a list of them for sorting .

but Unfortunately when the first score sent to the server , the function add it to the list and sent the sorted list to the client , dose not wait for all other scores from other Players . 
i tried to use  async & await in order to delay continuation of the method for about 30 seconds as the following :

```
 public  List<Player>  GetListOfWinners(int SentScore , string _SentPlayerID )
    {
        List<Player> PlayersList = new List<Player>();
        //Add to the List 
        PlayersList.Add(new Player { PlayerID = _SentPlayerID, Score = SentScore });

        DelayMethod();
        //Order It
        List<Player> SortedList = PlayersList.OrderByDescending(p => p.Score).ToList(); 
        // sent fULL SORTHEDlist to the Clients
        return SortedList;

    }

    private async void DelayMethod()
    {
        await Task.Delay(30000);
    }
```

but it dosn`t work , so what should i do ?

Comment: Does this method get called simultaneously for each player? I only see one players score being sent

Comment: yes , at the beginning a Sudoku game  is sent for all players , after fixed amount of time the client side for each player calculate the score and sent it to the server side for this method( GetListOfWinners)

Comment: There is something i dont understand. You create a new list for each request, add one player, then sort the list? it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me either. Please describe, what exactly this method is supposed to do. Where should the other players come from?

Comment: I assume you are new to concurrent programming. Even if you had the service setup for correct multithreaded handling, you will only ever have one instance of this method running per client, thus individual `PlayerList` instances, and each will only have the data from the calling client.

Comment: Can you include the code for starting the Sudoku game, sending it out to all players? The easiest implementation would be to have a `static List<Player> PlayersList` at that point, which gets updated as each client returns its score, waiting on something like a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) for all scores to be sent in, then returned to each client.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov .. hmmm I have just realized that the server create a new list for each request which should not happened .

Comment: @EagleBeak I supposed that all clients deal with the same instance of the server and only one version of the method .

Comment: @MikeGuthrieو thanks a lot for illustrating the problem , I did not not know about concurrent programming ,after reading your comment i read an article talking about WCF Concurrency,then i tried to use 
   [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
                 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
 and i already made static List<Player> PlayersList but still having  the problem of one instance / client , so  would you please explain more this part :"  waiting on something like a ManualResetEvent for all scores to be sent in, then returned to each client."

Answer (score 1):

I've created a very basic service as a sample to show how you can accomplish some of your goal. It is provided as a means to introduce you to constructs such as [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) and [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx).

In my ISudokuConcurrentService.cs:

```
namespace SudokuTest
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.ServiceModel;

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISudokuConcurrentService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        SudokuGame ClientConnect();

        [OperationContract]
        List<Player> GetListOfWinners(int SentScore, string _SentPlayerID);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class SudokuGame
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string PlayerID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int TimeLimitInSeconds { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Player
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string PlayerID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Score { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my SudokuConcurrentService.svc.cs:

```
namespace SudokuTest
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading;

    public class SudokuConcurrentService : ISudokuConcurrentService
    {
        static int playerCount = 0;
        static List<Player> PlayersList = null;
        static object ListLock = new object();
        const int TimeLimit = 120;
        static ManualResetEvent AllPlayerResponseWait = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public SudokuGame ClientConnect()
        {
            lock (ListLock)
            {
                if (PlayersList != null)
                {
                    // Already received a completed game response -- no new players.
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return new SudokuGame()
                {
                    PlayerID = "Player " + Interlocked.Increment(ref playerCount).ToString(),
                    TimeLimitInSeconds = TimeLimit
                };
        }

        public List<Player> GetListOfWinners(int SentScore, string _SentPlayerID)
        {
            lock (ListLock)
            {
                // Initialize the list.
                if (PlayersList == null) PlayersList = new List<Player>();

                //Add to the List 
                PlayersList.Add(new Player { PlayerID = _SentPlayerID, Score = SentScore });
            }

            // Now decrement through the list of players to await all responses.
            if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref playerCount) == 0)
            {
                // All responses received, unlock the wait.
                AllPlayerResponseWait.Set();
            }

            // Wait on all responses, as necessary, up to 150% the timeout (no new players allowed one responses received, 
            // so the 150% should allow time for the last player to receive game and send response, but if any players have 
            // disconnected, we don't want to wait indefinitely).
            AllPlayerResponseWait.WaitOne(TimeLimit * 1500);

            //Order It
            List<Player> SortedList = PlayersList.OrderByDescending(p => p.Score).ToList();
            // sent fULL SORTHEDlist to the Clients
            return SortedList;

        }
    }
}
```

Note that the main limitation of this sample is that it only allows a single game to be played during the life of the service. I'll leave running multiple games as an exercise for you, but will point out that you will need to track everything being done now per each game. You will likely want to bundle up the list and wait locks into objects, which you can then store another list of, in some manner such as [`MemoryCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx)